# traefik kubernetes crd health check

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-health-check

I am using Traefik 2.1 with kubernetes CRD's.  My setup is very similar to the [user guide](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guides/crd-acme/).  In my application, I have defined a livenessProbe and readinessProbe on the deployment.  I assumed that traefik would route requests to the kubernetes load balancer, and kubernetes would know if the pod was ready or not.  Kubernetes would also restart the container if the livenessProbe failed.  Is there a default healthCheck for kubernetes CRD's?  Does Traefik use the load balancer provided by the kubernetes service, or does it get the IP's for the pods underneath the service and route directly to them?  Is it recommended to use a healthCheck with Traefik CRD's?  Is there a way to not have to repeat the config for the readinessProbe and Traefik CRD healthCheck?  Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a default healthCheck for kubernetes CRD's?

No

> Does Traefik use the load balancer provided by the kubernetes service,
>   or does it get the IP's for the pods underneath the service and route
>   directly to them?

No. It directly gets IPs from the endpoint object

> Is there a way to not have to repeat the config for the readinessProbe
>   and Traefik CRD healthCheck ?

Traefik will update its configuration when it sees that endpoint object do not have IPs which happens when liveness/readiness probe fails.So you can configure readiness and liveness probe on your pods and expect traefik do honour that.

> Is there a way to not have to repeat the config for the readinessProbe
>   and Traefik CRD healthCheck

The benefit of using CRD approach is its dynamic in nature. Even If you are using the CRD along with health check mechanism provided by the CRD , the liveness and rediness probe of pods are still necessary for kubernetes to restart the pods and not send traffic to the pods from other pods which uses  the kubernetes service corresponding to those pods.

Comment: If I omit the livenessProbe, then if a container hangs then it will not be restarted.  correct?

Comment: Also if i delete the readinessProbe then any other pods which attempt to use that service might be sent to a pod that isnt ready since only traefik is aware of the healthCheck.  correct?